# Getting error on resetting stepper in angular

Tags: angular

I am using angular stepper in my project. I have two screens i want if user comes to step 1 any how by clicking back button or by direct clicking on label i want reset stepper by using `reset()` function. but when i am clicking on back button or direct on label. i am getting below error

**ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Below is my code

**stepper-example.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild,ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'stepper-example',
  templateUrl: 'stepper-example.component.html'
})
export class StepperExampleComponent {

  @ViewChild(MatStepper)
  matStepper: MatStepper;
  userTypeSelected = false


  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef){}

    selectUser(){
      this.userTypeSelected = true
      this.cd.detectChanges();
      this.matStepper.next();
    }

    prev(){
        this.userTypeSelected = false
        this.matStepper.reset()
        this.cd.detectChanges();
    }

    selectionChange(event){
        if(event.selectedIndex === 0){
          this.matStepper.reset()
        }
    }
}
```

**stepper-example.component.html**

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)">
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
        <mat-icon>check</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>
    <mat-step [completed]="userTypeSelected">
        <h3>Click to fo next</h3>
        <button (click)="selectUser()">User Type - 1</button> <br>
        <button>User Type - 2</button>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
        Information -2
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>

    <button type="button" (click)="prev()" *ngIf="matStepper.selectedIndex > 0">Back</button>
```

Stackblitz link is

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-routed-stepper-nvjnml

back button is working only if i remove `selectionChange` event .

please let me know why i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `this.matStepper.reset()` on the `selectionChange` callback of your stepper.

Indeed, each time the stepper will change it will call `this.matStepper.reset()` that will make the stepper change and so call `selectionChange` again, etc... You end up with an infinite loop hence the **ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Looking at the Angular Material documentation here https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview it doesn't seem that there is an easy way to reset the  stepper when you click on a previous step on it.

The **Back** button only seems to be the good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same functionality while attempting to solve the issue myself. It turns out you can actually accomplish what you're after using the `selectionChange` event, but you have to jump through a hoop or two.

My approach was to use `window.setTimeout` to allow the `selectionChange` callstack to complete prior to me resetting the stepper control.

The modified `selectionChange` method could look something like this:

```js
selectionChange(event){
  if(event.selectedIndex === 0 && event.previouslySelectedIndex !== 0){
    window.setTimeout(() => this.matStepper.reset(), 0);
  }
}
```